# В чем отличие пайплайна от джобы Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, devops, jenkins-pipeline

Мне нужно понять, что называют джобой в Jenkins, а что пайплайном.

Исходя из источников из интернета:

> Jenkins Pipeline — набор плагинов, позволяющий определить жизненный цикл сборки и доставки приложения как код.

> Jenkins Jobs — это набор задач, которые выполняются последовательно, как определено пользователем.

Из этого описания кажется, что набор задач (Джоба) — это набор этапов (тесты, линтеры, SonarQube, сборка артефакта и т.д), а набор плагинов (Пайплайн) — это какие именно плагины используются. Но я думаю, что моё восприятие про пайплайн не верно, потому что кажется, что два эти термина используют как синонимы.

[image: Джобы]

На скрине — две джобы: JavaTpoint Maven, JavaTpoint Pipeline. Но когда говорят "запустить пайплайн", имеется ввиду запустить джобу? Это синонимы или есть отличие?

Answer (score 1):

Это несколько разные понятия. Джоба это элемент Jenkins'a, который содержит в себе описание выполняемой задачи, флаги настроек, репозиторий с Jenkinsfile'ом (или сам код пайплайн-скрипта). А пайплайн это часть джобы, которая описывает непосредственно процесс сборки и тестирования приложения.

Comment: То есть пайплайн — это сами этапы джобы? Или в пайплайн входит только сборка и тесты, но не входит отправка образа в Nexus и деплой?

Comment: Да, пайплайн это этап джобы. Пайплайн может и собирать, и запускать тесты, и заливать артефакты, и деплоить их на сервера.